# pedir tres números y salvar error

Tags: java, try-catch

b tardes!!, tengo un problema, estoy tratando de pedir tres números y que no "pete" cuando metan un valor incorrecto, pero cuando me da el error por no meter el valor correcto el contador sigue, pidiendo el número siguiente y el del error lo pierdo. Alguna solución?
paso código:

```java
double mayor=0;
boolean error=true;

do 
{
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        try 
        {
            System.out.print("Ingrese el número " +(i+1)+": " );
            num1= Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
            error=false;
        }//end try
        catch (Exception er)
        {
            System.out.println("ERROR!");
        }//end catch

        if (num1>mayor)
        {
            mayor=num1;
        }//end if
    }//end for
}while (error==true);
System.out.print("El Número Mayor es: "+mayor);
```

Comment: ```while(error!=true)```, y no estas poniendo error en true cuando entra al catch

Comment: No, así entra en bucle infinito y no deja de pedir numeros

Comment: Eso es porque la logica es confusa.. estas confundiendo el pedido de numeros con los errores... fijate de pensar la logica de otra forma..

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, está claro que estoy confundido, por eso pido ayuda. Seguiré pensando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > Pero cuando me da el error por no meter el valor correcto el contador sigue...

El problema radica en que has colocado los bucles al revés. Primero debería ir el bucle `for` como el principal y el `do-while` como secundario y de este modo, podrás pedirle al usuario que vuelva a ingresar el número si es que lo había ingresado de forma incorrecta.

De esta manera debería de funcionar:

```java
double mayor=0;
boolean error=true;
for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    do
    {
        try 
        {
            System.out.print("Ingrese el número " +(i+1)+": " );
            num1 = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
            error=false;
        }
        catch (Exception er)
        {
            System.out.println("ERROR: Lo que ingresaste no es numero!");
        }
    }while(error == true);
    if (num1 > mayor)
    {
        mayor=num1;
    }
}
System.out.print("El Número Mayor es: "+mayor);
```

Aunque esto puede funcionar, habrá un error lógico, debido a que, la variable `error` quedaría valiendo `false` si el usuario en la primera vez ingresó un dato de forma correcta pero posteriormente, en la segunda vez que ingrese un dato de una manera incorrecta, la condición del bucle `do-while` dará `false`, debido a que, `error` no será igual a `true`.

Por lo tanto, una solución a este problema es agregar una asignación de `true` a la variable `error` adentro del bloque `catch`:

```java
double mayor=0;
boolean error=true;
for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    do
    {
        try 
        {
            System.out.print("Ingrese el número " +(i+1)+": " );
            num1 = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
            error=false;
        }
        catch (Exception er)
        {
            error = true;
            System.out.println("ERROR: Lo que ingresaste no es numero!");
        }
    }while(error == true);
    if (num1 > mayor)
    {
        mayor=num1;
    }
}
System.out.print("El Número Mayor es: "+mayor);
```

De esta manera el programa ya no tendría errores lógicos. Pero aún así, este algoritmo solo servirá para trabajar con valores positivos. Es decir, si el usuario solo ingresara valores negativos, el valor mayor siempre sería `0` porque ese es el valor por defecto de la variable `mayor`.

**Una posible solución** es agregar una condicional en la cual se cumplirá cuando el usuario ingrese por primera vez un dato (se lo detecta cuando `i == 0`) y ese será el valor por defecto de la variable `mayor`.

Código completo:

```java
double mayor=0;
boolean error=true;
for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    do
    {
        try 
        {
            System.out.print("Ingrese el número " +(i+1)+": " );
            num1 = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
            error=false;
        }
        catch (Exception er)
        {
            error = true;
            System.out.println("ERROR: Lo que ingresaste no es numero!");
        }
    }while(error == true);
    if (num1 > mayor || i == 0)
    {
        mayor = num1;
    }
}
System.out.print("El Número Mayor es: "+mayor);
```

Answer (score 1):

La logia de tu solucion esta alrevez, en ves de usar el `while(error == true)` debes hacer seguir el proceso en los siguientes dos casos.

1. Mientras error sea falso ( no existe error) `error == false`.
2. Mientras números ingresados menos a 3 `i < 3`.

```java
double mayor=0;
// error inicia en false porque no existe errores al principio
boolean error=false;
int i = 0; // << inicio i en cero

// preguntara nuevo numero 3 veces o hasta que error sea true
while (error == false && i < 3 ) {
  try 
  {
    System.out.print("Ingrese el número " +(i+1)+": " );
    num1= Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
    i++;  // << aumento i 
  }//end try
  catch (Exception er)
  {
    // cuando entra aqui existe un error
    error=true;
    System.out.println("ERROR!");
  }//end catch

  if (num1>mayor)
  {
    mayor=num1;
  }//end if
}

System.out.print("El Número Mayor es: "+mayor);
```

Estoy iniciando la variable `i` por fuera del `while` y la aumento `i++` dentro del `while` para así iterar parecido al `for` , pero con la validación de `error`; ten en cuenta que si sale error dejara de preguntar, ahora si lo que quieres es que sea tres números ingresados por obligación debes modificar el `while`

```java
  while( i < 3 ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Soy novato, así que igual me equivoco. Tal vez podrías usar un patrón, y evaluar luego si se cumple el dato introducido con el patrón indicado.
Podría ser algo como:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.regex.Matcher;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;
    public class prueba {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String[] userInput = new String[3];
            Scanner objScanner = new Scanner(System.in); 
            Pattern patron = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{1}");

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                System.out.print("Escribe un numero: ");
                userInput[i] = objScanner.nextLine();
                Matcher mat = patron.matcher(userInput[i]);
                while (!mat.matches()){  
                    System.out.print("Error, escribe un número: ");
                    userInput[i] = objScanner.nextLine();
                    mat = patron.matcher(userInput[i]);
                }
                System.out.println("Imprimo resultado: " + userInput[i]);    
            }    
        }
    }
```

De esta manera, el bucle se iterará hasta que coincida las entradas del usuario con el patrón que le indicas. En este ejemplo tendrás un arreglo con los 3 números formateados. No creo que las excepciones sirvan para este fin.
Disculpar si me equivoco o digo/hago una barbaridad.

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por vuestro aporte, de todos he aprendido algo